# Нужно сделать delay между сообщениями, и поменять немного код

Tags: python

```py
import telebot
import os
from random import *
from decimal import Decimal

myBot = telebot.TeleBot('1418080647:AAGvspahgeKDFgSSA5nCEw9j73NCzmEsNyM')

@myBot.message_handler(commands=['start','start_1'])
def get_command(message):
    if message.text == '/start':
        myBot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Тебя приветствует бот - CoffeMuch, который поможет тебе рассчитать твою сутучную норму коффеина.")
        get_mes(message)

@myBot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def get_mes(message):
    myBot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваш обьём чашки:')
    if message.text == "400":
        msg = myBot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ваш обьём чашки = 400")
        myBot.register_next_step_handler(msg, second_mes(message))
        obem = 400
        pass
    if message.text == "200":
        msg = myBot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ваш обьём чашки = 200")
        myBot.register_next_step_handler(msg, second_mes(message))
        obem = 200
        pass

def second_mes(message):
    myBot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваше количество чашек в сутки:')
    if message.text == "1":
        msg = myBot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ваш обьём чашки = 1")
        myBot.register_next_step_handler(msg, second_mes(message))
        obem = 1
        pass
    elif message.text == '2':
        msg = myBot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ваш обьём чашки = 2")
        myBot.register_next_step_handler(msg, second_mes(message))
        obem = 2
        pass


myBot.polling()
```

---

```
    Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "F:/py/venv/tg_beats_cg.py", line 42, in <module>
        myBot.polling()
      File "F:\py\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 455, in polling
        self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout)
      File "F:\py\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 513, in __threaded_polling
        raise e
      File "F:\py\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 479, in __threaded_polling
        self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
      File "F:\py\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 118, in raise_exceptions
        raise self.exception_info
      File "F:\py\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 69, in run
        task(*args, **kwargs)
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

нужно фиксануть эту ошибку, и обьяснить как можно сделать delay между сообщениями, и обьяснить почему отправляется Ваш обьём чашки: повторно[image: скрин с бота] огромное заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую сделать конечный автомат
https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial/docs/lesson_11/